# Wi-Fi Network can not scanned

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I am having problem with my recently bought SONY XPERIA SL. I have CISCO WAP4410N router, and its SSID cannot be scanned or connected (manually) on my phone, while being on AUTO CHANNEL selection mode. Where as I am using the same network previously for my iPhone and even for different laptops.

While when I change the channel manually to no 10, I am able to access the network.

Anybody can resolve this issue for me?

Answer (score 1):

An helpful app to resolve this might be [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyze), it shows the available (and perhaps conflicting) wifi channels and their strength.

Answer (score 0):

Is is quite possible that the channel it automatically chooses is too congested, or even not supported by your devices wifi card.

Comment: ...or that it is in an "invalid range". Not all channels are "legal" in all places. So the router might chose an "invalid" channel, and your XPeria refuses to use it.